# Show a sequence (Un) converges to $0$ in Normed space $(V, || ||)$. Where $U_{n+1} = U_{n}*sin(||Un||)$. And ||U_0|| = a. a is an element of [0,pi/2)

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, metric-spaces

I managed to prove that ||U_n|| is a decreasing sequence. 
By showing |sin(||Un||)|<1.

I  am struggling to prove that the sequence converges to the 0 vector in the Normed  Space. Any ideas? I found it would be sufficent to show  ||Un|| converges to 0 in the Reals.

Comment: $U_0 = a$ ? Something seems wrong about this unless $V = R$.

Comment: Sorry I have edited it, its meant to be ||U_0|| = a.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a hint:

The sequence $(\|u_n\|)$ is decreasing and bounded below, hence convergent to some value $\alpha$.  Using continuity, show that $$\alpha=\alpha\sin\alpha.$$ 
And assuming $\alpha\neq0$, you obtain a contradiction, so we must have $\alpha=0$.